# Change only a particular section in a file and skip the other sections

Tags: json, file, shell

I want to change only a certain section of a file that looks like this:

```
{
   "Section_A": {
    "ws/abc-Location01": 24, 
    "ws/abc-Location02": 67,
    "ws/abc-Location03:  101,
   },
   "Section_B": {
    "ws/abc-Location01": 33, 
    "ws/abc-Location02": 59,
    "ws/abc-Location03:  92,
   }
}
```

I want to change **ONLY the numeric values in field 2 in Section B**, based on match on the location name with an array, from a shell script.

For example, if `ws/abc-Location01` is present in my array in my script, its value should not be changed, else its value should be changed to the value of the 2nd field in file1.txt, where the 1st field contains location name (like `ws/abc-Location01`)

I'm not sure how to go about this, since a given location name occurs in each section. So how do I tell my script to ignore Section A, Section C and so on, and just change the value in Section B?

Comment: Is that the *exact* format for your file? It almost looks like JSON, but has trailing commas in places where they aren't legal in real JSON. If it actually _is_ JSON, you can use `jq` to edit it.

Comment: Why, yes it is! So, how would I edit it from my shell script?

Comment: Give me a minute to test my answer. :)

Comment: As an aside -- if you're doing this for use with Ansible (a configuration-management tool that generates shell scripts), I have an Ansible module that uses jq to perform in-place edits. Need to make sure it's actually a thing we released publicly before I can point you to it, though.

Comment: Nope, I'm not using Ansible.

Answer (score 0):

Using [jq](http://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```
# list all the keys in Section B into a bash array
keys_str=$(jq --raw-output '.["Section_B"] | keys | @sh' <test.json)
eval "keys_arr=( $keys_str )"

# determine which keys are not present in your other array
# assumes that the other array is associative for sanity
keys_to_change=( )
for key in "${keys_arr[@]}"; do
  [[ ${other_array[$key]} ]] || keys_to_change+=( "$key" )
done

for key in "${keys_to_change[@]}"; do
  # this is the inefficient way to do this, but it's much less code / easier
  # to show; in this case, we're changing everything listed to 0, since you
  # don't specify how you want to change them more precisely.
  jq --arg key "$key" \
    '.["Section_B"][$key] = 0' \
    <test.json >test.json.new \
    && mv test.json.new test.json
done
```

In general, syntax-aware tools are your best bet here -- just as folks asking similar questions about XML are told to use XMLStarlet or another XPath engine, using a proper JSON parser and generator is the Right Thing for making edits. This can require installing extra dependencies -- but it ensures that you're actually generating syntactically valid content.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand what your command does.. can you explain it please?

Comment: @Canzee, "don't understand" is rather broad. I've expanded this answer to be closer to the larger question you described, but if that expansion doesn't help, you'll need to be more specific with your follow-up questions.

Comment: This is starting to smell a bit more like "please write my code for me" than a focused technical question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your file is proper JSON (it does not *seems* to be the case in your sample file -- but you confirmed it in a comment), a few lines of your favorite script language should be sufficient.

As of myself, I used Python:

```
import sys
import json

data = json.load(sys.stdin)
data["Section_B"]["ws/abc-Location02"] = 9999
json.dump(data, sys.stdout,indent=True)
```

Assuming that file stored as "change.py"

```
# Original data (proper JSON)
$ cat data.json 
{
   "Section_A": {
    "ws/abc-Location01": 24, 
    "ws/abc-Location02": 67,
    "ws/abc-Location03": 101
   },
   "Section_B": {
    "ws/abc-Location01": 33, 
    "ws/abc-Location02": 59,
    "ws/abc-Location03": 92
   }
}

# Pipe original data to our filter
$ cat data.json | python change.py 
{
 "Section_A": {
  "ws/abc-Location01": 24, 
  "ws/abc-Location02": 67, 
  "ws/abc-Location03": 101
 }, 
 "Section_B": {
  "ws/abc-Location01": 33, 
  "ws/abc-Location02": 9999, 
  "ws/abc-Location03": 92
 }
}
```

---

If you want a shell only solution, `sed` might be sufficient:

```
cat data.json | sed '/Section_B/,/}/{/Location02/s/:[^,]*/ 9999/}'
```

This is obviously shorter; but much more fragile too...
On the bright side, this will process JSON-like files as well a proper JSON (assuming formated as in your example).