# Using cat and while read line inside awk

Tags: shell, awk

I am getting a syntax error for using cat and while read line inside awk.

**Sample code:**

```
awk '{
if( condition )
{
 array[FNR]=$1;
 cat file1.json | while read LINE; do 
 print LINE
 done;
}
fi
}' /home/user/spfile.txt
```

**My json file:**

```
{
   "Section_A": {
    "ws/abc-Location01": 24, 
    "ws/abc-Location02": 67,
    "ws/abc-Location03:  101,
   },
   "Section_B": {
    "ws/abc-Location01": 33, 
    "ws/abc-Location02": 59,
    "ws/abc-Location03:  92,
    "ws/abc-Location42:  92,
   }
}
```

**My array:** contains locations of various partitions like below:

```
array[15742] is nsg -> /ws/abc-Location42/uname/builds_nsg
array[15744] is bfr -> /ws/abc-Location63/uname/builds_bfr
array[15746] is pre -> /ws/abc-Location67/uname/builds_pre
array[15748] is sfjk -> /ws/abc-Location67/uname/builds_sfjk
```

**File2.txt**

```
abc5-blah30a:/vol/local13/abc-Location67
1000 598
abc5-blah30a:/vol/local14/abc-Location68
1000 186
abc5-blah30a:/vol/local14/abc-Location01
1000 256
abc5-blah30a:/vol/local14/abc-Location02
1000 15
abc5-blah30a:/vol/local14/abc-Location03
1000 765
```

**What I'm trying to do:**

- I need to change only Section B in my json file, and skip all other sections.
- I need to check the locations of the partitions in Section B and for all matches with the array, the numeric value on the right hand side shouldnt be changed.
- For all non-matches, the numeric value on the right hand side needs to be changed to the corresponding value from another file file2.txt.

**Example**

- There is a match for Location42 in my json file against the array, so I do NOT change it.
- But there is no match against the array for Location01,02,03 in the json file.
- So I need to look up the corresp values for these 3 locations against file2.txt.
- And I need to change them to 256, 15, 765.

Comment: You cannot use shell constructs *within* an awk script like that.

Comment: Also do you really want to print out the entire contents of `file1.json` for every line in `spfile.txt` that matches your condition?

Comment: I am actually just giving print LINE to test if it works.. But already I'm getting a syntax error for this.

Comment: Yes, you are getting a syntax error because that is a shell command and you are writing an awk script. Try telling us what you actually want to do instead of whatever it is you think you are doing there.

Comment: Ok. While I have the array populated and stored inside awk, I want to check a json file and change only a particular section in it, and skip all other sections.

Comment: What is it that you actually want to do?

Comment: You want to modify the json file based on contents of `spfile.txt`? What do the two files look like? What sort of modification are we talking about? Parsing json (in awk) is non-trivial if the json isn't rigidly formatted.

Comment: I ve edited my question to show how my files look and explain what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Don't use `awk` to parse a JSON file; use a JSON parser. Your task is specific enough that you should really be writing this in a language like Python (or Ruby, or Perl, but not shell).

Comment: You already have answers to a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24707698/change-only-a-particular-section-in-a-file-and-skip-the-other-sections As you didn't provide any feedback on them, it's hard to tell what really suits you.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux Could I use sed to accomplish this? I thought using sed would require me to specify one pattern with what it needed to be changed to.. But as you can see from my question above, I can't just specify one pattern and provide its replacement.

Comment: How do you pass the array to awk?

Answer (score 0):

**RTFM**.

`awk` is a powerful tool and can do many things (even if as chepner said python, perl or ruby could be more adapted to your problem) but it is not a magic tool that you can use without learning.

You simply cannot use any shell construct within a `awk` script.

Comment: Not an answer. And while your last sentence is sort of true, it's somewhat misleading, since something like `awk '{print $'${1:-2}'}'` is perfectly valid, and `${1:-2}` is a shell construct within an awk script. Although if you really wanted to be nitpicky you could say the whole thing is a shell construct used to generate an awk script which of course has no shell constructs.

Comment: @genisage You are right but I'm afraid my english is not good enough to find a better word :-( . But I'm sure you perfectly understood what I meant !